# Make a ggplot line plot where lines follow row order

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm making a ggplot line plot, or perhaps it would be better to describe it as a scatter plot with lines connecting the points in a specified manner. Here is my example data:

```
X<-c(-37,-25,-27,4,20,30,22,10)
Y<-c(-5,-9,10,15,-13,-0.04,4,0.03)
Day<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
DF<-data.frame(X,Y,Day)
```

The goal is to plot out the X Y points, and have lines connecting the points chronologically (Day 1 connected to Day 2, Day 2 to Day 3, ect). If I plot like so:

```
ggplot(DF,aes(x=X, y=Y, label=Day),legend=FALSE)+
geom_line(,size=0.3)+
geom_point( fill='red', shape=21)+
geom_text(size=7)+
theme_bw()
```

[image]

But as can be seen the points are connected increasingly up the X axis (Day 1 is connected to Day 3, Day 3 to Day 2, ect). Is there a way to change the default of the ggplot line plot to follow the pattern as laid out in the "Day" column? Or alternatively, to follow the ordering of rows in DF (both of which should yield the same results)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using your data,

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x=X,y=Y))+geom_point()+geom_path()
```

Produces this, which sounds like what you are asking(??)

[image]

Comment: ...they key point being that `geom_path` will follow the ordering of the data frame passed to it.

Comment: With the additional precaution of `DF <- DF[order(DF$Day),]`, to make sure your dataset is ordered.