# ggplot2: Recreating A plot of shrinkage from a book

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to recreate the following plot from Computer Age Statistical Inference.

[image]

I have the following data

```
Player,MLE,TRUTH,JS
1,0.345,0.298,0.2848934967658405
2,0.333,0.346,0.2807859008379247
3,0.322,0.222,0.2770206045706685
4,0.311,0.276,0.2732553083034123
5,0.289,0.263,0.26572471576889994
6,0.289,0.273,0.26572471576889994
7,0.278,0.303,0.26195941950164375
8,0.255,0.27,0.25408652730647174
9,0.244,0.23,0.25032123103921555
10,0.233,0.264,0.2465559347719594
11,0.233,0.264,0.2465559347719594
12,0.222,0.21,0.2427906385047032
13,0.222,0.256,0.2427906385047032
14,0.222,0.269,0.2427906385047032
15,0.211,0.316,0.239025342237447
16,0.211,0.226,0.239025342237447
17,0.2,0.285,0.23526004597019082
18,0.145,0.2,0.2164335646339099
```

I gave it a try, but it seems that my points are not connected by lines correctly.

[image]

Here is my code

```
js_player %>% 
  gather(type,value,2:4) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=value,y=type))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(group=Player),lty=2, alpha=1/4)+
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Related: [Make a ggplot line plot where lines follow row order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526618/make-a-ggplot-line-plot-where-lines-follow-row-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?geom_line`:

> `geom_line()` connects [observations] in order of the variable on the x axis".

Which is not what you want. You want them connected in the order TRUE - JS - MLE. Therefore `geom_path` is useful here:

> `geom_path()` connects the observations in the order in which they appear in the data

Thus, you need to massage your data accordingly. (1) Convert "type" to a `factor` with `levels` in the desired order. (2) Order the data according to "type" (`arrange(type)`). You *could* be more explicit and order by "Player" as well, but since we use `group = Player`, this is not needed. (3) Replace `geom_line` with `geom_path`.

```
df %>% gather(type, value, 2:4) %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels = c("TRUTH", "JS", "MLE"))) %>%
  arrange(type) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = type)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_path(aes(group = Player), lty = 2, alpha = 1/4) +
  theme_minimal()
```

---

Try on a smaller toy data set (easier to check if/how it works):

```
df <- read.csv(text = "Player,MLE,TRUTH,JS
1,1,2,3
               2,2,4,5
               3,5,5,4
               4,8,8,6")
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, stick to `geom_line` and use `coord_flip`:

```
df %>% gather(type, value, 2:4) %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels = c("TRUTH", "JS", "MLE"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = type, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = Player), lty = 2, alpha = 1/4) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal()
```